# How to get client id devexpress control in ascx

Tags: javascript, devexpress, ascx

I have a control stored in ascx file. In this control used 2 devexpress controls `ASPxTextBox` and `ASPxGridView`.
How can I get client side Id `ASPxGridView` in ClientSideEvent from `ASPxTextBox`?
I can't use `ClientInstanceName` because my control used on page many times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to handle the server-side Init event of your controls and set their ClientInstanceName in code. In the same way, you can write your JS functions to handle client-side events. Take a look at the [The general technique of using the Init/Load event handler](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/K18282) article on DevExpress that describes this (see Example #2).